# php echo string html with php-variables, can't break the php string

Tags: php, html, format, str-replace

I'm trying to echo a phpstring-message. This php string consists of html and php variables and comes form a database and i can't change that data.

```
$name = 'John';
$str = '<b>Hi {$name},</b><br/>How are you?';

echo $str;
```

So i'm trying to replace the php string, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
$str = str_replace('{', '\' . ', $str);                     
$str = str_replace('}', ' . \' ', $str);
```

I get:  `<b>Hi' . $name. ',</b><br/>How are you?`

How do i get the string like this?

```
<b>Hi John,</b><br/>How are you?
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this, you won't be able to replace it with a concatenation:

```
echo str_replace('{$name}', $name, $str);
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't know the name of the variable just use this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\{(.*?)\}/', $name, $str);
```

Comment: thanks ! But it have to be variable. So this time i'm using $name, but it also can be another variable...

Comment: @josser1995 I updated my answer hope this solves your problem

Comment: @josser1995 You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (FYI: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works (Welcome on SO!))

Answer (score 0):

it's already implemented in PHP, you can directly write the variable in double quote like this:

```
echo "<b>Hi $name,</b><br/>How are you?";
```

or for some more complex variables:

```
echo "<b>Hi {$user->name},</b><br/>How are you?";
```

Comment: If the string comes from the database you can't thread it as double quotes! The `$name` will be in the string as normal text

Comment: Sorry, I went back to test, because you have a lot of points, so you made me question myself and you're wrong, a string is a string and you can use it in double-quote. (Tested with PHP 5.5.2 and PDO)

Comment: I would love to see this! Just an example: This string is in OP's DB: `<b>Hi $name,</b><br/>How are you?` He fetch's the results in `$result` and with `echo $result["text"];` he can access the fetched text. You won't be able to tell PHP that it should interpret the text as doubled quoted

Comment: Did you read my answer to the end? You can simply write the second one like this:

`echo "<b>Hi {$result['name']},</b><br/>How are you?";`

Comment: @Rizier123 did a little bit of an experiment, fetching and all other stuff, and no, it doesn't get interpolated, worked on the evil `eval` thought

Comment: Yes i read your answer until the end, believe it or not, but i also read the entire question and there it says: *and comes form a database and i can't change that data* So the string which you print is in a variable from the database

Comment: @Ghost jeah with `evil()` you can parse it as doubled quoted, but I think it wouldn't be the nicest solution, speaking of that: saving html data in a DB also isn't nice

Comment: My bad, sorry, I went over the question a bit too fast and it's quite a strange way to use databases. Especially in the example OP used.